How to cluster spring-ai client?
I'm trying to use spirng-ai with its client config,but i cannot find the way to config it as a cluster to load balance,why?
Here's my dependency
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ai</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ai-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-ai.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ai</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ai-azure-openai-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

I'm trying to use spirng-ai with its client config,but i cannot find the way to config it as a cluster,why?

Why would Spring AI care about running in a cluster? Setting up multiple instances and putting a load balancer in front of it should be done outside of Spring AI, by some kind of deployment configuration. Or am I misunderstanding your question?
